# SKProductRequest not returning any results

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

I am trying to use iap's in my app. These are to buy in game gold and can be used more then once. I code the code from a noob tutorial and it works on there project can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#import "IAP.h"
#import "Money.h"

@interface IAP ()

@end

@implementation IAP;




#define kStoredData @"com.AlexApps.TinyTrucks"




+(void)myIAPWithItem:(NSString *)Item{
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        NSString *PurchaseAddress = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TTE_%@kGold" , Item]];
        //PurchaseAddress is the appId for this in app purchase
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:PurchaseAddress]];

        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];


    } else {
        UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Prohibited"
                            message:@"Parental Control is enabled, cannot make a purchase!"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [tmp show];

    }



}


#pragma mark StoreKit Delegate

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:{

                // show wait view here

                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:{

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                // remove wait view and unlock feature 2

                UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"Complete"
                                    message:@"You have unlocked Feature 2!"
                                    delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
                [tmp show];





                // apply purchase action  - hide lock overlay and
                NSLog(@"befvsda");

                // do other thing to enable the features

                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:{
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                // remove wait view here
                                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:{

                if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                    NSLog(@"Error payment cancelled");
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                // remove wait view here
                               break;
            }
            default:{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    // remove wait view here


    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];

    if (count>0) {
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];

        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.emirbytes.IAPNoob.01"];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];


    } else {
        UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Not Available"
                            message:@"No products to purchase"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [tmp show];

    }


}

-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request
{

}

-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to connect with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}



#pragma mark AlertView Delegate

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

The program gets to this line:

```
SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:PurchaseAddress]];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
```

Then it just stops and doesn't get anything back from apple.

Comment: 1. Paste your code here, don't make people cut and paste to see it.  2. Use apple's guide. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html 3. Put some breakpoints in your code and narrow it down to where it's failing or not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your delegate is set, you have `request.delegate = self;` but you're using `self` in a class method.  I don't see how that's working.

Change `+(void)myIAPWithItem:(NSString *)Item` to an instance method `-(void)myIAPWithItem:(NSString *)Item` then instantiate the Money class and call the method.  See if that helps.

Comment: Ok i changed that and i changed the kStoredData but still not luck. Same thing as before.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you created the set up for  product ID `com.emirbytes.IAPNoob.01` in your `iTunesConnect`.

If you are created, then check for spelling of your productID `com.emirbytes.IAPNoob.01` which is one you created in `iTunesConnect`

**UPDATE 1:** No `Bundle ID` is different, `Product ID` is different.

`Bundle ID` is the unique identifier which is used fo App. `Product ID` is the unique identifier which used to buy the Product List.

Let say `com.emirbytes.IAPNoob` is bundleID and

1. `com.emirbytes.IAPNoob.swords`   - is product ID to buy swords
2. `com.emirbytes.IAPNoob.soldiers` - is product ID to buy soldiers

To create `Product ID`, you've to go to [iTunesConnect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/) and Create one app, and have to setup Product ID in `Manage In-App Purchases`.

Comment: the kStoredData is not com.emirbytes.IAPNoob.01 it is the bundle id for my app. Is this what is should be? When the kStoreData is changed i get the same problem. kstoredata Updated in code.

Comment: I changed the kStoreData to my in app purchase Product id but still no luck. Do you have a sample project you could share.

Comment: check this links http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/ and http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_6_In-App_Purchase_Tutorial